# Sorting by a value in one "row" inside a jsonb

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

It's possible the answer to this is "don't use jsonb" but for now I'm trying to avoid creating another table.

I have a table which stores sign in times to various apps. A value for the column `apps_last_accessed` can look like this:

```
[
  {"name": "Atlassian", "local_id": null, "published": "2023-06-06T00:20:16.217Z", "external_id": "asdf"}, 
  {"name": "Bitbucket", "local_id": "3f46c949", "published": "2023-06-06T00:19:58.236Z", "external_id": "fdsa"}
]
```

When displaying a list of users who have signed into one app, I would like to be able to sort by `apps_last_accessed->published`, except scope it to the correct hash in the jsonb by specifying the `local_id` of `3f46c949`.

If I use `WHERE ... AND (apps_last_accessed @> '[{"local_id":"3f46c949"}]')`, that will narrow results to where a sign in to that app exists, but does nothing to narrow the JSONB hash that I want to sort by a value of.

I can break out the JSONB hashes into their own row with `SELECT ... jsonb_array_elements(apps_last_accessed)->>'published' as published` and that will let me sort by `published`, but the result rows are one for each hash in `apps_last_accessed`. I could also break out the local_id with `SELECT ... jsonb_array_elements(apps_last_accessed)->>'local_id' as local_id`, but I can't then add `AND local_id = '3f46c949'` to the WHERE because it's not a column.

Is there a way to sub-query what I need after breaking out the jsonb into their own rows? Or a different approach entirely? Again, I'm aware I can build out a table with typical relations where `published` is a normal datetime column but I'm looking to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you want to sort your table by the publish date of the json element whose local id matches a given value.

One option uses a subquery in the `order by` clause to unnest the json array, filter its elements and retrieve the corresponding date:

```
select *
from mytable t
order by (
    select j ->> 'published'
    from jsonb_array_elements(apps_last_accessed) as x(j)
    where j ->> 'local_id' = '3f46c949'
    order by 1 desc limit 1
)
```

The `order by` and `limit` clauses are here in case there is more than one row that matches the local id.

If you want to display that date in the resultset, we can phrase the logic with a lateral join instead:

```
select t.*, x.*
from mytable t
left join lateral (
    select j ->> 'published'
    from jsonb_array_elements(apps_last_accessed) as x(j)
    where j ->> 'local_id' = '3f46c949'
    order by 1 desc limit 1
) x(last_published) on true
order by x.last_published
```